Point within polygon in a certain distance of "point on surface"
I'm seeking for a random point pr in a certain distance r of a polygons "point on surface" (point guaranteed to lie within the interior of a surface) as illustrated by this figure (parts of circular arc drawn solid are within the polygon):

Preferred solutions are PostGIS or FME.

I take it the point you are after needs to be precisely the given distance away, rather than somewhere within the given distance?
A simple solution would be to ST_Project Points along the circle with radius of <distance> in intervals and choose one at random among those that ST_Intersects:
SELECT
  ply.*,
  rpt.geom
FROM
  <polygons> AS ply
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      projected::GEOMETRY AS geom
    FROM
      -- create azimuths to project to at set intervals
      GENERATE_SERIES(
        0.0::NUMERIC,
        (2*PI() - PI()/180.0)::NUMERIC, -- full circle with inclusive interval of [0, 359] degrees in radians
        (PI()/180.0)::NUMERIC  -- 1 degree interval in radians; change to whatever you want ( degree_interval * PI()/180.0 ), but smaller intervals mean more computations
      ) AS azm,
      -- create projected points at each azimuth interval
      LATERAL
        ST_Project(
          ST_PointOnSurface(ply.geom)::GEOGRAPHY
          <distance>,
          azm
        ) AS projected
    -- filter for those that intersect the Polygon
    WHERE
      ST_Intersects(ply.geom::GEOGRAPHY, projected)
    -- order those at random
    ORDER BY 
      RANDOM()
    -- fetch only one
    LIMIT
      1
  ) AS rpt
;


Note:
ST_Project is primarily built with geodetic calculations in mind, requiring the Point input to have a geographic coordinate reference (i.e. it requires an implicit cast to GEOGRAPHY) and <distance> to be in meter. However, as of PostGIS 3.4.0 ST_Project allows for GEOMETRY input, with <distance> being in the unit of the underlying CRS.
The query above assumes <polygons>.geom to be of type GEOMETRY and to have a geographic coordinate reference (e.g. EPSG:4326), casts back and forth between GEOMETRY & GEOGRAPHY to generate the projections with <distance> in meter and filter for intersection, and returns a GEOMETRY.
If your <polygons>.geom are in a suitable projection with a distance unit other than degree, you can remove all type casts from and to GEOMETRY & GEOGRAPHY and use a respective <distance> in that unit.

After playing around with 2DArcReplacer, LineOnAreaOverlayer and snapping randomly generated points, inspired by the above PostGIS solution I came up with an FME Workspace that does something similar:

The result in FME Inspector looks like this:

...but for my usecase PostGIS is preferable ;-)

You can draw a circle around your point, take its intersection with the polygon and ask for a point on that - ST_PointOnSurface() works fine on lines:
demo at db<>fiddle
select  st_pointonsurface(
            st_intersection(
                st_exteriorring(
                    st_buffer( st_pointonsurface(geom)
                              ,9
                              ,'quad_segs=16')
                ),geom
            )
        )
from your_table;


If you like laser precision, you can use an actual circle, CircularString. Generating it looks weird because there's no convenient constructor and most functions with "curve" and "circle" in the name actually produce LineString approximations.
select*,st_pointonsurface(
            st_intersection(
                format( 'CIRCULARSTRING(%s %s,%s %s,%s %s)'
                       ,st_x(st_pointonsurface(geom))+9
                       ,st_y(st_pointonsurface(geom))
                       ,st_x(st_pointonsurface(geom))-9
                       ,st_y(st_pointonsurface(geom))
                       ,st_x(st_pointonsurface(geom))+9
                       ,st_y(st_pointonsurface(geom))
                )::geometry
                ,geom
            )
        )
from your_table;

Despite the repetition, PostgreSQL planner knows to only run a single st_pointonsurface(geom) and take just one one st_x() and one st_y() from that.

Extra kudos for this "GIS Art" screenshot!
